# Convert from the IBM floating point to the IEEE floating point standard and vice versa in C#

Tags: c#, c, floating-point, ieee-754

I was looking for a way to convert IEEE floating point numbers to IBM floating point format for a old system we are using.

Is there a general formula we can use in C# to this end?

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_hexadecimal_floating-point
//
// float2ibm(-118.625F) == 0xC276A000
// 1 100 0010    0111 0110 1010 0000 0000 0000
//
// IBM/370 single precision, 4 bytes
// xxxx.xxxx     xxxx.xxxx xxxx.xxxx xxxx.xxxx
// s|-exp--|     |--------fraction-----------|
//    (7)                   (24)
//
// value = (-1)**s * 16**(e - 64) * .f   range = 5E-79 ... 7E+75
//
static int float2ibm(float fromFormat)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(fromFormat);
    int fconv = (bytes[3] << 24) | (bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[1] << 8)| bytes[0];

    if (fconv == 0)
        return 0;
    int fmant = (0x007fffff & fconv) | 0x00800000;
    int t = (int)((0x7f800000 & fconv) >> 23) - 126;
    while (0 != (t & 0x3)) {
        ++t;
        fmant >>= 1;
    }
    fconv = (int)(0x80000000 & fconv) | (((t >> 2) + 64) << 24) | fmant;
    return fconv; // Big-endian order
}
```

I changed a piece of code called *static void float_to_ibm(int from[], int to[], int n, int endian)*.

The code above can be run correctly on a PC.

*from* is a [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) float number.
*return value* is a [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian) IBM float number, but stored in type int.

Comment: This really saved my life, I wish I could reward you 50 reputation points to both of you speeding and Noam M, I just don't find how. A notice: in my case I had to read the bytes of the returned int in reverse order to get the printable output to windows-1252 encoded file (little endian). It was for SAS XPORT.

Comment: I'd love it if I could understand this well enough to expand it to 64-bit doubles. Which document is this implementation sourced from?

Comment: IEEE-754 `float` supports -0: I _think_ this value isn't treated correctly. Changing the first check to become `((fconv & 0x7fffffff) == 0)` should fix that problem. As the IBM  floating point format does support negative 0,  too, the sign bit could be added back but it doesn't seem negative 0 is maintained with IBM floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

An obvious approach would be to use textual representation of the number as the interchange format.

Comment: @mekrizzy since both systems can convert floats to and from text you can use text as your common language.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to convert one float to another.  It looks like the [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) format uses an odd format for its floats.  So when converting from XDR to standard floats, this code did it.

```
#include <rpc/rpc.h>

// Read in an XDR float array, copy to a standard float array.
// The 'out' array needs to be allocated before the function call.

bool convertFromXdrFloatArray(float *in, float *out, long size)
{
    XDR xdrs;
    xdrmem_create(&xdrs, (char *)in, size*sizeof(float), XDR_DECODE);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(!xdr_float(&xdrs, out++)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d:ERROR:xdr_float\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    xdr_destroy(&xdrs);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [speeding's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550367/convert-from-the-ibm-floating-point-to-the-ieee-floating-point-standard-and-vice/19554390#19554390), I added the following that may be useful in some cases:

```
/// <summary>

/// Converts an IEEE floating number to its string representation (4 or 8 ASCII codes).
/// It is useful for SAS XPORT files format.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="from_">IEEE number</param>
/// <param name="padTo8_">When true, the output is 8 characters rather than 4</param>
/// <returns>Printable string according to the hardware's endianness</returns>
public static string Float2IbmAsAsciiCodes(float from_, bool padTo8_ = true)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string s;
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Float2Ibm(from_)); // Big-endian order

    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    {
        // Revert bytes order
        for (int i = 3; i > -1; i--)
            sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(bytes[i]));
        s = sb.ToString();
        if (padTo8_)
            s = s.PadRight(8, '\0');
        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(bytes[i]));
        s = sb.ToString();
        if (padTo8_)
            s = s.PadRight(8, '\0');
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be *an example* of such usefulness?

Comment: Usefulness is SAS XPORT that is used for transferring datasets between statistical systems. A very special world