# QbyteArray to float

Tags: c++, qt, floating-point, qbytearray

I have a function that converts `QByteArray` to `float` and it works perfectly fine except when I feed it zeros I get `5.87747e-39` instead of `0.0`.

```
float QByteArrayToFloat(QByteArray f){
    bool ok;
    int sign = 1;

    f = f.toHex(); // Convert to Hex

    qDebug() << "QByteArrayToFloat: QByteArray hex = " << f;

    f = QByteArray::number(f.toLongLong(&ok, 16), 2);    // Convert hex to binary

    if(f.length() == 32) {
        if(f.at(0) == '1') sign =-1;     // If bit 0 is 1 number is negative
        f.remove(0,1);                   // Remove sign bit
    }

    QByteArray fraction = f.right(23);  // Get the fractional part
    double mantissa = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < fraction.length(); i++){  // Iterate through the array to claculate the fraction as a decimal.
        if(fraction.at(i) == '1')
            mantissa += 1.0 / (pow(2, i+1));
    }

    int exponent = f.left(f.length() - 23).toLongLong(&ok, 2) - 127;     // Calculate the exponent

    qDebug() << "QByteArrayToFloat: float number = "<< QString::number(sign * pow(2, exponent) * (mantissa + 1.0),'f', 5);

    return (sign * pow(2, exponent) * (mantissa + 1.0));
}
```

There is no useful function in `QByteArray` (`isEmpty()` doesn't work) that checks for zeros. I could do (after `toHex()`) `if(f.indexOf("00000000") == -1) return 0.0;` or `if(exponent = -127 && mantissa == 0) return 0.0;`, but is there a more elegant solution?

Also, what's interesting is that `QString::number(sign * pow(2, exponent) * (mantissa + 1.0),'f', 5);` works just fine and prints `"0.00000"`. However, as soon as I transform it back to float with `toFloat(&ok);` same thing happens.

Comment: I suggest reading about the [problems of representing floating point numbers](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html)

Comment: If the byte array contains the memory respresentation of a float variable you can probably avoid reinventing the wheel by using `QDataStream(f) >> myFloat`.

Comment: @Murphy What do you mean by memory representation? I tried the `QDataStream` approach, but I got `0.0` as a result for all inputs

Comment: That's how float values are stored in RAM, depending on how your compiler and architecture are handling them. If the array is from a different source then of course the representation may differ; you could try if changing the byte order before reading the stream fixes this (default for `QDataStream` is big endian, using an Intel machine you probably have little endian).

Comment: @Murphy I tried 
 `float a;
 QDataStream output(f);
output.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian); // and BigEndian
output >> a;`
, but I still get zeros for all inputs

Comment: Allright, then this is a dead end if you don't have the possibility to use `QDataStream` for filling the array, too.

Comment: @Murphy Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out there's a better solution for `QByteArray` to `float` conversion using bit shifts and `reinterpret_cast`. It also handles the zero values.

```
float QByteArrayToFloat(QByteArray arr)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559, "Only supports IEC 559 (IEEE 754) float");

    quint32 temp = ((char)arr[0] << 24)|((char)arr[1] << 16)|((char)arr[2] << 8)|(char)arr[3]; // Big endian
    float* out = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&temp);

    return *out;
}
```

Comment: Another related way to get the float in the right format. http://stackoverflow.com/a/44075329/999943

Comment: I think instead of (char) type cast. we must use (quint8) as it is unsigned ov even better, static_cast<quint8>

Answer (score 2):

I cite from this [document](https://users.cs.duke.edu/%7Eraw/cps104/TWFNotes/floating.html):

> #### Denormalized Numbers
>
> If you have an exponent field that's all zero bits, this is what's
> called a denormalized number. With the exponent field equal to zero,
> you would think that the real exponent would be -127, so this number
> would take the form of 1.MANTISSA * 2-127 as described above, but it
> does not. Instead, it is 0.MANTISSA * 2-126. Notice that the exponent
> is no longer the value of the exponent field minus 127. It is simply
> -126. Also notice that we no longer include an implied one bit for the mantissa.
>
> #### Zero
>
> You can think of zero as simply another denormalized number. Zero is
> represented by an exponent of zero and a mantissa of zero. From our
> understanding of denormalized numbers, this translates into 0*2-126 =
> 0. This sign bit can be either positive (0) or negative (1), leading to either a positive or negative zero. This doesn't make very much
> sense mathematically, but it is allowed.

After correcting your code just for zero case to:

```
int exponent = - 126;
// and
return (sign * pow(2, exponent) * (mantissa + 0.0));
```

I get the answer **0.0**.

Comment: I tried `int exponent = f.left(f.length() - 23).toLongLong(&ok, 2) - 126; return (sign * pow(2, exponent) * (mantissa));` and I got the zero alright, but when I tried with `QByteArray hex =  "3f6c5d8d"`  I got `0.84660` instead of `0.923302`

Comment: The exponent field for 0.923302 is not zero, i.e. it equals 01111110b. Hence, you should use the code for non-denormalized numbers (your original version). Please, [read the document carefully](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~raw/cps104/TWFNotes/floating.html)